# How to render HTML from markdown, which contains tables, using Sphinx

Tags: python, markdown, python-sphinx

I have a *.md files which I am going to put into documentation with help of Sphinx. These files contains tables.

The documentation said to do the following:

- pip install recommonmark
- add:

  source_parsers = {
          '.md': 'recommonmark.parser.CommonMarkParser',
      }

  source_suffix = ['.rst', '.md']

to the conf.py

As a result the tables do not rendered normally. Rest of the md syntax rendered ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like recommonmark does not support tables, as noted in [issue #3](https://github.com/rtfd/recommonmark/issues/3) and [PR #68](https://github.com/rtfd/recommonmark/pull/68).

Comment: it is really weird:)

Comment: @ArtemZhukov no, just not supported. :) One person tried to remedy that issue in that PR. Perhaps you can offer a remedy to the open source software project, or modify the PR source in your installation of recommonmark, to get it to work.

Comment: Yes. tables are a non-standard feature. Any Markdown implementation which does support them, does so as an add-on. And as they are non-standard, every implementation has implemented a slightly different syntax for them. Pure Markdown implementations do not support tables.

Comment: @Waylan thanks for clarifying this. I was thinking tables are standard.